# Getting MemoryError in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am running following code on python to print nos. in the range specified for even floating nos.:

```
def float_range(begin,end,step):  
    i=begin-step
    numbers=[]

    while i!=end:
        i=i+step
        numbers.append(i)
    return numbers      #returning the list

a=2
b=4
c=.1
for j in float_range(a,b,c): #calling function
    print j
```

and it gives following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\b53659\Desktop\My python\float_range.py", line 13, in <module>
    for j in float_range(a,b,c):
  File "C:\Users\b53659\Desktop\My python\float_range.py", line 7, in float_range
    numbers.append(i)
MemoryError.
```

but in above code if i replace

```
    a=1
    b=1000
    c=1
```

it gives correct output i.e. prints no. from 1 to 1000.
why is it happening? thanks in advance

Comment: http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html

Comment: `while i <end` or use an `epsilon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main flaw in code is `while condition !=`.

You are checking if `i!=end`. Here step is 0.1, which is actually something like 0.100000000000001. So when you reach to last iteration(as per your logic)

```
i = 3.9 + step = 4.000000001
```

and you have `end= 4.0`
 and `i!=end`

So your `while loops condition i!=end is True always` and loop continues forever and throw memory error

I have debugged you code And found the actual values in the list. You can see from the screen shot then `4.0` value never generated instead 4.0000001 get generated 
[image]

This code would work as you expected:

```
def float_range(begin,end,step):
    i=begin-step
    numbers=[]

    while i < end:
        i=i+step
        numbers.append(i)
    return numbers      #returning the list
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `c=.1`, which makes the counter floating point. When the loop gets to the 'end' (in `float_range`), i will be something like `4.00000000001` or `3.9999999999998`, and so it doesn't compare equal to the integer 4.

There are a few possible solutions:

- Only use integers (whole numbers, not 0.1)
- Use python's fixed-point numbers (the `decimal.Decimal` class)
- Make the loop end condition `i < end` instead of `i!=end`

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
def float_range(begin,end,step):  
    i = begin-step
    numbers = []

    while i < end:
        i += step
        numbers.append(i)
    return numbers      #returning the list

for j in float_range(2,4,0.1): #calling function
    print round(j, 2)
```

This way you'll be sure that the loop stops when it's above `end` even if the float doesn't hit the exact integer value.

I also made two other changes apart from `while i < end:`. You can use `+=` instead of `i = i+step`. I've also rounded the floats down, since it'll print something like `3.9000000000000017` if you don't.

I hope this helps.